# How to sort this list effectively?

Tags: python, algorithm

I Have the following input:

```
list = ["A-g(x)|**B**","J-Gustav-add(y)|**f**(g(y))","V|**A**"]
```

The "-" is showing that the next"word" is a new one and the "|" divites every string into two parts (first
| second.

Output should be a sorted list by the second part.

output:

```
list = ["V|**A**","A-g(x)|**B**","J-Gustav-add(y)|**f**(g(y))"]
```

I just can't find a method to make this nice only brute Force comes into my mind

Comment: Just a tip: Don't use `list` as a variable name, because it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
l = ["A-g(x)|B","J-Gustav-add(y)|f(g(y))","V|A"]

print(sorted(l, key=lambda a:a.split("|")[1]))
# ["V|**A**","A-g(x)|**B**","J-Gustav-add(y)|**f**(g(y))"]
```

You can choose the key to sort it by using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).  Since the key is on the right side of the `"|"`, I split the string into two and choose index one. This sorts it correctly. Remember that `sorted` returns a new list while `list.sort` will modify the list. Both work exactly the same otherwise.

**Note:** Try not to shadow built-in names like `list` in your code. It can cause bugs to appear quite often since you overwrite the built-in.